# How to format ruby logger?

Tags: ruby, logging

How do you format the ruby logger?

Comment: Describe "messy line". The output is pretty much whatever you send it.

Comment: The leading status id is super annoying: `I, [2014-01-23T17:41:35.268796 #8066]  INFO -- : event=updateSiteStats`

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
logger = Logger.new('nice.log')

logger.formatter = proc do |severity, datetime, progname, msg|
   "NICE: #{msg}\n"
end

logger.info("I like cheese.")

# nice.log:
NICE: I like cheese.
```

Answer (score 38):

If you want to format only the time, you can easily do it with [datetime_format](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#method-i-datetime_format) and the standard [format specification](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html).
For example, if you do:

```
# Set the logger:
logger = Logger.new($stdout)
logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
logger.datetime_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

logger.info("This is an info log...")
logger.error("This is an error log...")
```

You will end up with logs such as:

```
I, [2015-01-20 14:02:29#17329]  INFO -- myProg: This is an info log...
E, [2015-01-20 14:02:29#17329] ERROR -- myProg: This is an error log...
```

If, instead, you want to completely customize your log, you can use [logger.formatter](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger/Formatter.html).
For example, if you do:

```
# Set the logger:
logger = Logger.new($stdout)
logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
logger.formatter = proc do |severity, datetime, progname, msg|
    date_format = datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    if severity == "INFO" or severity == "WARN"
        "[#{date_format}] #{severity}  (#{progname}): #{msg}\n"
    else        
        "[#{date_format}] #{severity} (#{progname}): #{msg}\n"
    end
end

logger.info("This is an info log...")
logger.error("This is an error log...")
```

You will end up with logs such as:

```
[2015-01-20 14:48:04] INFO  (myProg): This is an info log...
[2015-01-20 14:48:04] ERROR (myProg): This is an error log...
```

Comment: Good information, but to keep consistent spacing, just use printf instead.  You can set a specific string spacing with a number such as `sprintf "%5.5s", severity`

Comment: Or just use `#{severity.ljust(5)}`