# How to format ruby logger to this?

Tags: ruby, logging

The default style in ruby logger is:

```
SeverityID, [Date Time mSec #pid] SeverityLabel -- ProgName: message
# => D, [2013-11-25T13:31:03.451024 #38180] DEBUG -- : <message...>
```

and I want to make it looks like:

```
SeverityLabel [Date Time mSec #pid]: message
# => DEBUG [2013-11-25T13:31:03.451024 #38180]: <message...>
```

I know I can format it like this:

```
logger.formatter = proc do |severity, datetime, progname, msg|
   "severity [#{datetime}]: #{msg}\n"
end
# => DEBUG [2013-11-25 13:37:45 -0800]: <message...>
```

but the datetime in proc does NOT look like what it showed in default. I've tried using datetime_format

```
logger.datetime_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L"
```

but it has NO effect on my logger...

Also, I cannot find #pid either

any thoughts?

I've seen the following post:

[How to format ruby logger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382252/how-to-format-ruby-logger)

and the doc:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html

---

Thanks to Some Guy's reply, This is what I ended up doing:

```
logger.formatter = proc do |severity, datetime, progname, msg|
   "#{severity} [#{datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%6N')} ##{Process.pid}]: #{msg}\n"
end
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this:

```
 "#{severity} [#{datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L')}]: #{msg}\n"
```

Comment: Thanks for the super quick respond. That works. and for the pid I just found that I can do Process.pid